# Screen Space Reflection using Directx 9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, directx-9, directx-12

I want to implement screen space reflection using directx9 c++ but dont know how to start till i study lots of article but get only shader code 
like 
http://roar11.com/2015/07/screen-space-glossy-reflections/
http://casual-effects.blogspot.in/2014/08/screen-space-ray-tracing.html

So please provide me to start and use the shader of screen space reflection

Comment: Or Can I implement it at directx-9 or not

Answer (score 0):

For showing the surrounding reflection use Environment Mapping in Direct3D 9.
Cubic and Spherical Environment mapping will help you do the desired work.